# How to find the Network capabilities like gsm and cdma

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a requirement like I need to find programatically, that perticular IOS device having    GSM, CDMA and SPI network capabilities or not.

So, if there is any way to find, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `UIDevice` class, you can figure out if your application is running on a iPod or an iPhone. To get this information, access the property named model which will return an NSString of iPhone or iPod touch. However, there may be times when you need more specifics, for example is the iPhone the latest device, a 3GS or on the flip side, is the iPod a first or second generation device?

Accessing the system hardware will reveal the information we need to make the above distinctions. We’ll use a category to extend the UIDevice class with a method that returns the “machine” type as a string. Begin with the interface definition below:

```
@interface UIDevice(machine)
- (NSString *)machine;
@end
```

To access the hardware type we’ll call a function in the standard C library:

```
sysctlbyname(const char *name, void *oldp, size_t *oldlenp, void *newp, size_t newlen);
```

[Read more here...](http://iosdevelopertips.com/device/determine-if-iphone-is-3g-or-3gs-determine-if-ipod-is-first-or-second-generation.html)

**Or**

import `#import <sys/utsname.h>`

then, `NSString *deviceName = [Classname myDeviceModel];`

```
+ (NSString*)myDeviceModel 
  {
    struct utsname deviceInfo;

    uname(&deviceInfo);

    NSString *deviceNameTemp = [NSString stringWithCString:deviceInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *deviceDictionary =
    @{

   //simulators.
   @"i386":     @"iPhone Simulator",
   @"x86_64":   @"iPad Simulator",

   //iPhone's.
   @"iPhone1,1":    @"iPhone",
   @"iPhone1,2":    @"iPhone 3G",
   @"iPhone2,1":    @"iPhone 3GS",
   @"iPhone3,1":    @"iPhone 4",
   @"iPhone3,2":    @"iPhone 4(Rev A)",
   @"iPhone3,3":    @"iPhone 4(CDMA)",
   @"iPhone4,1":    @"iPhone 4S",
   @"iPhone5,1":    @"iPhone 5(GSM)",
   @"iPhone5,2":    @"iPhone 5(GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPhone5,3":    @"iPhone 5c(GSM)",
   @"iPhone5,4":    @"iPhone 5c(GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPhone6,1":    @"iPhone 5s(GSM)",
   @"iPhone6,2":    @"iPhone 5s(GSM+CDMA)",

   //iPads.
   @"iPad1,1":  @"iPad",
   @"iPad2,1":  @"iPad 2(WiFi)",
   @"iPad2,2":  @"iPad 2(GSM)",
   @"iPad2,3":  @"iPad 2(CDMA)",
   @"iPad2,4":  @"iPad 2(WiFi Rev A)",
   @"iPad2,5":  @"iPad Mini(WiFi)",
   @"iPad2,6":  @"iPad Mini(GSM)",
   @"iPad2,7":  @"iPad Mini(GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPad3,1":  @"iPad 3(WiFi)",
   @"iPad3,2":  @"iPad 3(GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPad3,3":  @"iPad 3(GSM)",
   @"iPad3,4":  @"iPad 4(WiFi)",
   @"iPad3,5":  @"iPad 4(GSM)",
   @"iPad3,6":  @"iPad 4(GSM+CDMA)",

   //ipods
   @"iPod1,1":  @"iPod 1st Gen",
   @"iPod2,1":  @"iPod 2nd Gen",
   @"iPod3,1":  @"iPod 3rd Gen",
   @"iPod4,1":  @"iPod 4th Gen",
   @"iPod5,1":  @"iPod 5th Gen",

   };

    NSString *deviceName = commonNamesDictionary[deviceNameTemp];

    if (deviceName == nil) 
    {
        deviceName = machineName;
    }

    return deviceName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am looking for any other direct API or core API instead like this, because in future new mobile comes, then I need to add that in the list again.